# Telerik Grid MVC: Get the object passed to ClientEvent functions in javascript side

Tags: javascript, ajax, model-view-controller, grid, telerik

I have a little tricky question. I have a Telerik Grid with some ClientSide Events:

```
.ClientEvents(events => events
    .OnDataBinding("SetAjaxParameter")
)
```

In the function `SetAjaxParameter` I set the paramters for the ajaxBinding:

```
function SetAjaxParameter(event) {
    event.data = {
        name: $('#paramterID').val(),
        value: $('#valueID').val()
    };
};
```

So in my controller I have access to the passed parameters 'name' and 'value'.
But I want to define the call to SetAjaxParameter() in javascript and not in the Setup of the TelerikGrid. Is that somehow possible? So i have to get this event-Objekt which is passed by the Grid to my function. But i can't figure out what type of objekt it is neather how to get it.

You may ask why: i want to seperate cshtml and javascript files and my javascript gets loaded after the html has been loaded, so the function for the databinding-Event is not available yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, it's pretty simple to to that. I just had to write following code snippet:

```
    $('#GridName).bind('dataBinding', function (event) {
        SetAjaxParameter(event);
    });
```

And on the next AjaxCall by the grid, the desired parameter get passed to my controller.